# JS/React function returning string property but returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function:

```
const getNameListMarkdown = (props: Props) => {
  if (isDefined(props.details)) {
    return (
      Object.keys(props.details).map(x => <p>{props.details![x].name}</p>)
    );
  }

  return '';
};
```

For some reason, when I then try to render this it is rendered as `[object Object], [object Object]`, for example if I have two objects in the list. If I console log the `Object.keys` it writes out the strings as it should in the `.name` space. So it should return a string but it doesn't render as such. And if I check what I get back where I call this function it receives a `vNode` object where the string can be seen in the children array. Does anyone know how to properly do this?

Comment: Are you sure you need exclamation point here: details![x] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<p>{props.details![x].name}</p>` is [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html). When it is evaluated you get a *React [element](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html)* (which is an object), not a string of HTML.

Meanwhile, `Array.prototype.map` gives you an array. So you end up with an array containing two objects.

When you call (directly or implicitly) `.toString()` on an array, you get a string made up of each member of the array (hence *two* `"[object Object]"`s)

---

If you want a string, use a template literal instead of JSX:

```
.map(x => `<p>${props.details![x].name}</p>`)
```

Comment: what does the ! mean in between details and [x]?